# Specific Image Spawn

Tags: ios, swift, image, cocoa-touch, pixel

How can I edit this code so the spawnRandomPosition function also doesn't allow the image to spawn 45 pixels down from the bottom of the screen? So the top 45 pixels of the screen cannot be spawned in.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

private var addOne = 0

func spawnRandomPosition() -> CGPoint
{                
    let width  = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height

    let centerArea = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.midX - 75.0 / 2,
                            y: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.midY - 75.0 / 2,
                            width: 75.0,
                            height: 75.0)

    while true
    {
        let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(width))), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(height))))


        if !centerArea.contains(randomPosition)
        {
            return randomPosition
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
if let view = recognizer.view {
    view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                          y:view.center.y + translation.y)
     }
recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
    addOne += 1
    score.text = "\(addOne)"
    smallDot?.center = spawnRandomPosition()

}
}
    }
```

Comment: I am seeing your question over and over again but I can figured out what are your trying clearly

Comment: I agree. I saw this same question a few hours ago. Why are you deleting your questions and creating new ones **instead** of editing the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a different approach, is not elegant but you could use if's

```
func spawnRandomPosition() -> CGPoint  {

let screenWidth  = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height
boolean valid = true;
repeat
{
   let randomPosition = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()),y:arc4random())
   if(randomPosition.x >screenWidth || randomPosition.y < 45 || (randomPosition.x > ((screenWidth/2)- 37.5) && randomPosition.x< ((screenWidth/2)+ 37.5)  || (randomPosition.y > ((screenHeight/2)- 37.5) && randomPosition.y< ((screenHeight/2)+ 37.5))
      valid = false
}while(valid = false;)
}
```

But of course you should take in consideration that could arc4random() give back a very high number and end up with an inefficient solution, so you could use rand() instead

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the error, "rand() is unavailable in Swift: use arc4random instead."

Comment: I updated my code, but the parameters I set aren't being used.

Comment: I don't understand why you divide by height and width, forget it i was seeing the other person response

Comment: My code above is working besides the minY variable any idea why?

Comment: The edit stop me, but you are taking away miny  when y position starts from  up wich is the area you are trying to avoid, is good you take away 45 but then in the result you have to add it again so it skips the first 45 positions

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify function spawnRandomPosition a bit:

```
func spawnRandomPosition() -> CGPoint
{
    let minY: CGFloat = 45.0

    let width  = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height - minY

    let centerArea = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.midX - 75.0 / 2,
                            y: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.midY - 75.0 / 2,
                            width: 75.0,
                            height: 75.0)

    while true
    {
        let randomPosition = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height),
                                     y:minY + CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width))

        // Check for 'forbidden' area
        if !centerArea.contains(randomPosition)
        {
            return randomPosition
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code, but it ins't spawning within the parameters in the code.

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code or add some logging?

Comment: The centerArea code works and it doesn't spawn inside it, but the minY isn't working and it is spawning above the 45 pixels that it says not to spawn in. The code runs fine, and I have tried cleaning it and restarting Xcode multiple times.

Comment: This should work is what i was saying, but didn't explain correctly, forget it he added miny yo width is supposed to be with height

Comment: He did add it to height.

Comment: @D.Mika the minY variable still isn't working and the image is still spawning in the 45 pixels